# Azure publish errors for custom html helper

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am very new to Microsoft Azure, but when I publish my application and try to access it, I get this error -

```
error CS1928: ‘System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper’ does not contain a definition for ‘SportSiteHref’ and the best extension method overload ‘mySports.Helpers.HtmlHelpers.SportSiteHref(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)’ has some invalid arguments
```

I am obviously using HtmlHelpers, with this example.

```
<div class="padding-top padding-bottom">
    <a href="@Html.SportSiteHref()"><img class="bottom-panel-image responsive" src="/images/fullsite/HomePagePromo.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

This works locally and when I FTP to my live site like I have been doing for years.

Why does Microsoft Azure trap this as an error?

Comment: Have you tried to delete bin and obj folders and rebuild it again?

Comment: @TomSun yes, I tried that